# Trying to set one of my 3-way ANOVA variables as a random factor, but getting this error message: (in R)

Tags: r, anova

I've got three categorical groups (levels in brackets): Species (3), SedLayer (2) and Site (10). Since I only have a sample size of 58 in total, and i'm interested in the effect of species on sediment characteristics, I want to set Site as a random factor in my ANOVA. So i'm trying to run:

```r
res1 <- aov(pH ~ Species * SedLayer + (1|Site), data = dat)

summary(res1)
```

But then I get this error message:

```r
*Error in contrasts<-(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels*
```

Which I really don't understand because I've got 10 sites... Could it have to do with the amount of observations within each level? Or is this a bug?

Thanks for any help you can give me!

Comment: Have a look at a package for mixed-models like "nlme"

Answer (score 1):

```
library(nlme)
res1 <- lme(pH ~ Species * SedLayer, random = ~1|Site, data = dat)
summary(res1)
```

Without an data example I can neither show nor evaluate the result

Comment: Sorry, i'm not sure how to give a data example. But if I understand your answer correctly, it's not possible for me to just run an anova with a random factor, I have to switch to a mixed effect model?

Comment: you can do the anova afterwards: anova(res1)

Comment: Maybe? `aov(pH ~ Species * SedLayer + Error(Site), data = dat)`